# Why is Q dense in R?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a topological space $S$ and an arbitrary subset $E$. Then if the closure of $E$ given by $\bar{E} = S$, we say that $E$ is dense in $S$.

How can we prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ is dense in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the standard metric topology?

I intended to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ is dense in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the topological sense, not the usual "between two $\mathbb{R}$ there is a $\mathbb{Q}$". Of course, both might be equivalent, but that remains to be proved.

Comment: Can you prove the $n=1$ case?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was thinking that if $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense, then there must be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that it contains all rationals and there is some real number that is not in it. I want to show that no such closed set exists. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1yM4hav

Comment: Precise your metric. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric (i.e. $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$, and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

1. [$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_Every_Two_Reals_Exists_a_Rational).
2. It suffices to show $\forall x=(x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $x\in I=(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\cdots \times (a_n,b_n)\cap \mathbb{Q}^n\neq \emptyset$. That is $\exists q=(q_i)\in \mathbb{Q}^n$, s.t. $q\in I$.

Comment: Updated link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_two_Real_Numbers_exists_Rational_Number

Answer (score 2):

Something to think about (not a proof):
The closure of a subset is the *minimal closed superset*. What must a superset of $\mathbb{Q}$ look like?
It cannot have a maximal or minimal element, certainly.
Maybe you could make one out of closed intervals around each point of $\mathbb{Q}$, but it would be impossible to make each of this intervals disjoint (think about the space between each rational).
Trying to construct a closed superset always leads us to the whole real line, and hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct $\mathbf{R}$ is many ways, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers) for instance. The first one (by Cauchy sequences) is the usual one. In it (I encourage you to find it somewhere and to sudy it, as it is very enlightening), $\mathbf{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}$ by contruction. It is also the case in the second construction, from Dedekind cuts.

Answer (score 0):

$Cl(A)=AUAd$
here $A=Q$
so, $Cl(Q)=QUQd$
Now,
  as $Qd=R$ 
so, $Cl(Q)=QUR$
and $QUR=R$
Hence $Cl(Q)=R$
So $Q$ is dense in $R$ as from definition of dense set " In a topological space , $A$ is subset of $X$ Then $A$ is dense in $X$ iff $Cl(A)=X$

Answer (score 0):

Since x < y, we have y−x>0. from the Archimedian property for a  positive integer n such that
n(y−x)>1...(classics Proof) between two reals we can find irrationnal
Seet More At:
[Proof verification that Q is dense in R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524125/proof-verification-that-q-is-dense-in-r)